# SessionFactory NoClassDefFoundError in Hibernate 5 and Spring 4 MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 4.2.5.RELEASE and Hibernate 5.1.0.Final. I've configured all beans and pom.xml. I run the app and get:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/SessionFactory
```

My pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

HibernateConfig.java:

```
import mojaapka.dao.UserDAO;
import mojaapka.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import mojaapka.model.User;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bonafide");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("pass");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    return properties;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public UserDAO userDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    return new UserDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
}
}
```

Are there some dependecies I am missing, or are the beans configured incorrectly?

Comment: are you using IntelliJ Idea as your IDE???

Comment: Yes, I'm using Intellij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your sessionfactory bean to the below configurationa and see if it makes any difference:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.xxxxxx.configuration.hib" })

public class HibernateConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.XXXXXX.spring.component" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }
    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
        properties.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, false);
        properties.put(Environment.USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE,true);
        properties.put(Environment.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY,"org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
        properties.put(Environment.CACHE_PROVIDER_CONFIG,"/ehcache.xml");
        properties.put(Environment.USE_QUERY_CACHE, true);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

************imports********

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
```

Comment: There is some kind of progress I guess, now I have the following erorr: SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean

Comment: do you still have the autowired annotation, remove it and then try again

Comment: No, I do not have that annotation anymore.

Comment: I've copied it and adjusted to my code and unfortunately I'm still getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean

Comment: Try updating your porm.xml to <properties>
  <java-version>1.8</java-version>
  <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  <spring.security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
  <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
  <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
  <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
 </properties>

Comment: Also why do you have transactionmanager from hiberante5 and sessionfactory from hibernate4.. i have the following imports. Check the imports in the updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107425/discussion-between-learningphase-and-zenn1337).

Comment: Now it works, thank you. Anyways, any ideas why it can't run with Hibernate 5?

Comment: I think they might have different packages in 4 and 5